# No Username specified in startup packet

Tags: node.js, postgresql, macos

I am opening up a project from a year and a half ago and my local PostgreSQL database is not working. I am using a react front end, with a Node.js back end. The Node module I am using to connect with the local database is pg.pool. The error I get when I submit the data through pg.pool is:

```
Error with query for user  error: no PostgreSQL user name specified in startup packet
```

I was reading on the internet and apparently the client has to submit a username to the backend for the Database to open up. The internet suggested opening the pg_hba.conf file and checking that the users are correct, but I checked the file and the users for the PostgreSQL is set to all, so I don't think that is the problem. Here is that file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Here is my pool.js file that connects the node server to the postgresql instance running locally, it uses a if else statement incase I want to connect locally or in case I want to connect to heroku:

```
const pg = require('pg');
const url = require('url');

let config = {};

if (process.env.DATABASE_URL) {
  // Heroku gives a url, not a connection object
  // https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-pool
  const params = url.parse(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
  const auth = params.auth.split(':');

  config = {
    user: auth[0],
    password: auth[1],
    host: params.hostname,
    port: params.port,
    database: params.pathname.split('/')[1],
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };
} else {
  config = {
    host: 'localhost', // Server hosting the postgres database
    port: 5432, // env var: PGPORT
    database: "workout_app_prime", // CHANGE THIS LINE! env var: PGDATABASE, this is likely the one thing you need to change to get up and running
    max: 10, // max number of clients in the pool
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000, // how long a client is allowed to remain idle before being closed
  };
}

// this creates the pool that will be shared by all other modules
const pool = new pg.Pool(config);

// the pool with emit an error on behalf of any idle clients
// it contains if a backend error or network partition happens
pool.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

module.exports = pool;
```

Other relevant facts: yesterday morning working on a different project my computer crashed, PostgreSQL wasn't working when I tried to reopen that project because the project didn't terminate correctly, So I deleted the .pid file and restarted the computer then it started working.

When I made this database a year and a half ago I was running postgreSQL 12, now I am on 13.

I am running on Mac OS 10.15, idk if that is relevant.

Anybody have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Please show the node.js connection code.  Are you using the single connection uri connection string or the broken out kwargs style?

Comment: @jjanes, I added the file that creates the module that connects the sever to the database, Idk what you mean by using uri connection string, I think it uses kwargs.